# How LinkedHashMap in java adding node in same array index where there is already a node?

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

By my understanding about internal working of **LinkedHashMap**, it stores values in a array of **Node**. where Node contains fields :

```
class Node<K,V> {
 int hash;
 K key;
 V value;
 Node<K,V> next;
 Node<K,V> prev;

}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, LinkedHashMap stores insertion order and to maintain that order it stores Node which is inserted before the current node at '**prev**' and node which inserted after current node at '**next**'.
Then where it stores the new node which having same index value like current node ?

Comment: In case of same bucket location, the new Entry will be stored as next node of the existing Entry. Considering there's only one entry at that location then that Entry's next would be your newly added Entry

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, it just replaces the old value with the new value if the key is the same

Comment: yeah. But what when key is different and index is same ?